# Change Firebase data coming from angularfire2

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage, angularfire2, ionic3

I have a database which stores a node like this:

```
-KdFlSK9eqzRDPd_I71I
     address: 
     heats: 
     image: 2017-02-18T10:30:15.025Z.jpeg
     title:
```

Inside the image tag, there is the filename of a file stored in Firebase Storage. What I would like to do is get the full path to get the file from Firebase Storage before `2017-02-18T10:30:15.025Z.jpeg` is inserted inside the image source. So basically, alter the data before render.

**[Answer]**

Very simple - I did not change the data from firebase, I simple set the new data to a new variable which doesn't show if not set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as shown below.You just need to put `downloadURL` on your `image` property after the image has been saved in the firebase storage.

***Note:*** This is just a sample code where I used.Please adjust it according to your situation.

```
 takeBillPhoto(billId: string, imageURL: string) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(this.userId);
    return storageRef.child(billId).child('billPicture')
      .putString(imageURL, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/png' })
      .then(pictureSnapshot => {
        this.billList.update(billId, { picture: pictureSnapshot.downloadURL });
      });
  }
```

Comment: i've had it like that but wasn't sure it was correct because of the tokens in the url and the rules inside firebase

Comment: If you set the rules correctly on the storage then no problem.In other words, no one can access your images if those are private.